# Let's get critical: Mar 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Software Quality Assurance & Testing Stack Exchange](http://sqa.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How to test baby alarm](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7802/how-to-test-baby-alarm)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [performance-testing systems on virtual machines that normally run on physical machines](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7709/performance-testing-systems-on-virtual-machines-that-normally-run-on-physical-ma)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to Organize Tests for Software That's Already Developed?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7840/how-to-organize-tests-for-software-thats-already-developed)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Release methodology for complex distributed system](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7696/release-methodology-for-complex-distributed-system)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to use rollup command in selenium ide?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7801/how-to-use-rollup-command-in-selenium-ide)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [BDD living documentation for Product Owners](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7804/bdd-living-documentation-for-product-owners)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Strategy to handle legacy bugs](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7813/strategy-to-handle-legacy-bugs)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Selenium IDE Store variable in Javascript of Page](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7871/selenium-ide-store-variable-in-javascript-of-page)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to estimate "how many servers our company sould purchase for this web app" with load/performance testing?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7809/how-to-estimate-how-many-servers-our-company-sould-purchase-for-this-web-app-w)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Test Automation Using Ruby Selenium Web Driver](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7748/test-automation-using-ruby-selenium-web-driver)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

Answer (score 2):

I answered needs improvement to nearly all of the Questions but the majority of the answers were quite good.

The main issues I see in that list of questions:

1. Formatting was overall very poor and made the questions very difficult to interpret. Basic editing here to improve the questions would be a massive benefit for the community in general.
2. The questions were (and when browsing the site in general) poorly worded. Again, aggresive moderation and updating of questions will be beneficial here.

The answers to nearly all of the questions were top-notch, well formatted and overall great. The questions were really the problem.